# Python to parse nested JSON values that can be null sometimes

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to parse the following and pull out `primary_ip` as a variable. Sometimes `primary_ip` is "null". Here is an example of the JSON, code and the most recent error I am getting.

```
{
  "count": 67,
  "next": "https://master.netbox.dev/api/dcim/devices/?limit=50&offset=50",
  "previous": null,
  "results": [
   {
      "id": 28,
      "url": "https://master.netbox.dev/api/dcim/devices/28/",
      "name": "q2",
      "display_name": "q2",
      "device_type": {
        "id": 20,
        "url": "https://master.netbox.dev/api/dcim/device-types/20/",
        "manufacturer": {
          "id": 15,
          "url": "https://master.netbox.dev/api/dcim/manufacturers/15/",
          "name": "Zyxel",
          "slug": "zyxel"
        },
        "model": "GS1900",
        "slug": "gs1900",
        "display_name": "Zyxel GS1900"
      },
      "device_role": {
        "id": 4,
        "url": "https://master.netbox.dev/api/dcim/device-roles/4/",
        "name": "Access Switch",
        "slug": "access-switch"
      },
      "primary_ip": {
        "id": 301,
        "url": "https://master.netbox.dev/api/ipam/ip-addresses/301/",
        "family": 4,
        "address": "172.31.254.241/24"
      },
```

Example Python

```
import requests
import json

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Token 63d421a5f733dd2c5070083e80df8b4d466ae525',
    'Accept': 'application/json; indent=4',
}

response = requests.get('https://master.netbox.dev/api/dcim/sites/', headers=headers)
j = response.json()

for results in j['results']:
    x=results.get('name')
    y=results.get('physical_address')

response2 = requests.get('https://master.netbox.dev/api/dcim/devices', headers=headers)
device = response2.json()
for result in device['results']:
  x=result.get('name')
  z=result.get('site')['name']
#  if result.get('primary_ip') != None
  y=result.get('primary_ip', {}).get('address')

  print(x,y,z)
```

I get the following error when I run it:

```py
ubuntu@ip-172-31-39-26:~$ python3 Netbox-python

  Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "Netbox-python", line 22, in <module>
        y=result.get('primary_ip', {}).get('address')
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: So what was wrong with the previous line where you did a test for `None`?

Answer (score 2):

Which value is `None`? Is it the `primary_ip` or is it `address` ?

you could try the following:

```py
y = result.get('primary_ip', {}).get('address, 'empty_address')
```

This will replace any `None` values with `empty_address`

---

Update:

I have just ran your code and got the following output:

```
LC1 123.123.123.123/24 site1
q1 172.31.254.254/24 COD
q2 172.31.254.241/24 COD
```

After running this:

```
import requests
import json

headers = {
    "Authorization": "Token 63d421a5f733dd2c5070083e80df8b4d466ae525",
    "Accept": "application/json; indent=4",
}

response = requests.get("https://master.netbox.dev/api/dcim/sites/", headers=headers)
j = response.json()

for results in j["results"]:
    x = results.get("name")
    y = results.get("physical_address")

response2 = requests.get("https://master.netbox.dev/api/dcim/devices", headers=headers)
device = response2.json()

for result in device["results"]:
    x = result.get("name")
    z = result.get("site")["name"]

    if result.get("primary_ip") != None:
        y = result.get("primary_ip").get("address")

        print(x, y, z)
```

I am not sure of the expected output but the code doesn't throw any errors. From looking at the code, it seems there were a few indentation errors, where things didn't match up in terms of where they should have been indented.

Comment: Sorry - the address value is null }, "primary_ip": null, I now get this error ubuntu@ip-172-31-39-26:~$ python3 Netbox-python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Netbox-python", line 23, in <module>
    y = result.get('primary_ip', {}).get('address', 'empty_address')  
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
ubuntu@ip-172-31-39-26:~$

Comment: Have you ran what I pasted? It seems to run ok?

Comment: awesome! no problem, please can you mark this answer as useful and give it a tick. :)